# Can we make a Game on this site?

Tags: feature-request

I've seen these 3 rgb cubes and thought of making a little game with these and I want to ask straight forward:

> Can we make a little online Game as gimmick on this website

Do the operators allow a little gimmick to this site, made by the community?
I mean there many things to consider like safety of the website and the servers and for that code review of the communitys work, which means work and with work it means money.
The game shouldn't be a Triple A game, maybe just a tap game or sth else small.

Comment: Maybe the cubes could chase the mouse, because they want to cuddle, that would be a nice game

Comment: What value do you think this would add, specifically? Most users come here not to play games or discuss them, but to discuss _making_ games. This is a very different thing from playing a game.

Comment: Arguably, our reputation system is already a game, a gamification of expertise. I often joke that "StackExchange is my favourite RPG" - you can grind and earn points that help you level up and unlock new class abilities (privileges), as well as earning achievements (badges) you can show off on your player profile. ;) So, to be interesting to me personally, a game for this site would similarly help teach/encourage constructive use of the site. If someone could invent a game that helps new users learn to make good posts, or use search effectively, I'd be very interested. :)

Comment: @DMGregory From a certain perspective, SO made a game to make the game you propose: [The Stack Overflow Comment Evaluator 5000™](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comment-evaluator-5000). Initially, I had thought it was a CYOA, but after extensive 'play' I now deem it to be a clicker.

Comment: Related on Gaming.SE: [Feature-Request: Mini games on sidebar to play for fun](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13120/80914)

Answer (score 3):

Not likely.

Game Dev Stack Exchange gets operated and maintained by Stack Overflow, Inc. That's the company maintaining [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) plus [a couple of hundred other sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

GDSE's mission is as a Q&A site and knowledge repository. Adding a game to the site is neat, but doesn't further that goal, and Stack Overflow, Inc's developers are fairly busy as-is.

Stack Overflow periodically launches minigames across the network for holidays, but they are unlikely to attach an ongoing game to this site.

Whilst your enthusiasm's appreciated, you're probably better off spending that energy on your own little games.

Comment: If they really want to see this through, there might be a way to make it as a browser extension, that detects when you're on GameDev.StackExchange and injects the necessary script. Then there's no buy-in needed from the development team, and it's strictly opt-in for users who want to play, with no impact on other users of the site.

Comment: Right, users can freely create userscripts which overlay a game on this site.

Comment: If you do make a user-script using any of the elements of the site please make sure to check the Terms of Service, particularly Trademark guidance.

https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service